# Convert Json to gson from InputStreamReader

Tags: java, json, spring, gson

I got a JSON from URL, it looks like:|

```
   {"total_users_count":1,
     "users":[
              {"first_name":"jan",
               "email":"admin@localhost",
               "city":null,
               "position":"",
               "experience_years":"5 - 8",
               "salary_expectations":"0 - 7300"}
              // ,{ ... }
            ]
    }
```

In this respons will be more users. My code:

```
URLConnection urlConnection = url.openConnection();
    urlConnection.setRequestProperty("Authorization", "Basic " + authStringEnc);
    InputStream is = urlConnection.getInputStream();
    InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(is);
    System.out.println(is.toString());
    System.out.println(isr.toString());



   CandidateDTO candidateDTO = new Gson().fromJson(isr, CandidateDTO.class);

    // using the deserialized object
    System.out.println(candidateDTO.total_users_count);
    System.out.println(candidateDTO.first_name);
    System.out.println(candidateDTO.email);
    System.out.println(candidateDTO.city);
    System.out.println(candidateDTO.position);
    System.out.println(candidateDTO.experience_years);
    System.out.println(candidateDTO.salary_expectations);


private class CandidateDTO {
    int total_users_count;
    Map <String, String> first_name;
    String email;
    String city;
    String position;
    Integer experience_years;
    Integer salary_expectations;

}
```

Unfortunately, this code doesn't work and I can't add a user to my Map. What's wrong with this?

Comment: users is not map but array.

Comment: I'm not familiar with GSON but if if works like Jackson you'd need to either point it to the value of "users" (i.e the substring containing the `List<CandidateDTO>`) or provide a pojo that's mapped to the outer json object (and which has a field named `users` with an appropriate type).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

users is a collection(array of object), so you need to create a collection like this.

```
public class CandidateDTO {
    int total_users_count;
    List<User> users = new ArrayList<User>();
    //Set<User> users = new HashSet<User>();
}
public class User{
    String first_name;
    String email;
    String city;
    String position;
    String experience_years;
    String salary_expectations;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Your DTO does not match the json document you posted. Some of the data types are even wrong. Something more like this should work.

```
private CandidatesDTO {
    int total_users_count;
    List<CandidateDTO> users;
}

private class CandidateDTO {
  String first_name;
  String email;
  String city;
  String position;
  String experience_years;
  String salary_expectations;
}
```

And then when you are deserializing, use the "Candidates" DTO instead of the individual one:

```
CandidatesDTO candidates = new Gson().fromJson(isr, CandidatesDTO.class);
```